# Django - Get gravatar from view

Tags: python, django, gravatar

I'm using [django-gravatar](https://github.com/nvie/django-gravatar) in templates to display the avatars of my users.

Now I'd like to get the URI of an avatar from a view.
I tried to use the [template tag functions](https://github.com/nvie/django-gravatar/blob/master/gravatar/templatetags/gravatar.py) like

```
from gravatar import templatetags
_get_gravatar_id('test@test.com')
# or
gravatar_for_email('test@test.com')
```

But the functions are not defined
How can I access them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import them.

```
from gravatar.templatetags.gravatar import _get_gravatar_id, gravatar_for_email
```

Comment: `_get_gravatar_id()` is not importable (maybe private) but I will use `gravatar_for_email()` because it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like that project exposes the URL in python. It only provides those tags.

If you really want the image URL in python, it isn't hard to create yourself. The [Gravatar site](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/) has instructions for how to create it, but basically:

```
from django.utils.hashcompat import md5_constructor

email_hash = md5_constructor(email.strip().lower()).hexdigest()
url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/%s" % email_hash
```

Comment: Since I already use this library, I wanted to take advantage of the work already done and try not to repeat myself

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to generate visually pleasing, abstract, user-specific user profile images. With Sionade21's answer as my guide I implemented it as follows. I had to tweak Sionade21's answer because hashcompat is deprecated in 1.5.

Views.py:

```
from hashlib import md5

def my_view(request):
    email_hash = md5(my_user.email.strip().lower()).hexdigest()
    avatar_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/%s" % email_hash + 
                 "?s=35&d=identicon&r=PG"
```

Template(s):

```
<img src={{ avatar_url; }}</img>
```

This worked great.

Eg: http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7c40983cf4dd3b13108bc427025326c0?s=35&d=identicon&r=PG

I went one step further and saved/stored avatar_url in my database as a user attribute rather than generate it on the fly every time. I hope this helps the next person who stumbles across this question/answer.